# No puedo generar la vista de los posts en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

Sigo este video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywxIElNbcj4&index=12&list=PLMTiAh6qhda1-MVtXe1vs_99CghP5pd01

Al hacer click a los posts individuales no me carga la vista y me sale este error:

> "An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method Post::getPostById()
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\application\controllers\article.php
>
> Line Number: 11
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once"

Dice que no reconoce el método getPostById(). ¿Me habrá faltado cargar alguna library?

En este repositorio tengo los archivos:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/aplicacion

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario que cargues el modelo dentro del *Controlador*.

```
public function post ($id ='')
{
    $this->load->model('post');
    $fila = $this->post->getPostById($id);
}
```

Si tus *files* contienen clases, estos deben contener mayúsculas, en tu caso, cambia el nombre de **post.php** a **Post.php** y agregale `model` o `m`. Ejemplo: **Post_m.php** o **Post_model.php**.